# How to install Google Apis Drive v3 via command line on Ubuntu-18.04

Tags: google-drive-api, nuget, nuget-package, ubuntu-18.04

I have been trying to install `Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v3` using [this source](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v3/) with the difference that I have `Ubuntu-18.04` instead of Windows.
I know it may be a simple question but I have been trying research how to do that from this morning. I installed `sudo apt install nuget` on my machine and have been trying to add packages or as in this case the `Google.Apis.Drive.v3` package but no luck.

I went through [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558718/how-to-access-nuget-repository-from-net-core-using-visual-studio-code) which was useful, but does not carry information I was able to replicate on my Linux machine.

Also [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887112/how-can-i-access-the-nuget-package-manager-console-on-ubuntu-18-04-2), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56387680/python-google-drive-api-file-delete-method-broken) and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56387680/python-google-drive-api-file-delete-method-broken). But also this last one is for Windows and was not very useful.

How do I install Google Apis Drive V3 via command line easily as it is documented for windows but on `Ubunbtu-18.04`?

Thanks for pointing to the right direction for solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

The way you install your Drive API's library is **depending on the programming language you are aiming to use**. These are the following commands to run depending on the different languages to interact with the API (with their respective links to the source of the setup):

- [Python](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python):

`pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib`

- [C#/.NET](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet):

Create a new Visual C# Console Application project in Visual Studio.

Open the NuGet Package Manager Console, select the package source nuget.org, and run the following command:

```
">Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v3
```

- [Java](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java):

`gradle init --type basic
mkdir -p src/main/java src/main/resources`

- [Node.js](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs):

`npm install googleapis@39 --save`

- For the Browser check out the steps to follow [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js)

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something.

**NOTE:** For all Ubuntu-18.04 users that wish to install via command line the correct way is: `sudo dotnet add package Google.Apis.Drive.v3`

Comment: Hello and thanks for reading the question. I have been trying your solution in may different ways. However I get the same result, and it seems it is not possible to install google.apis.drive.v3 on my Ubuntu machine. I have `Visual Studio Code`, `Ubuntu 18.04`. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yH0-LGKvVpc) tutorial and am able to open the `localhost`. However, when I try to include the `Google.Apis.Services`. Nothing does not seems to be working.

Comment: I am attaching a print-screen [here](https://i.imgur.com/PVGLNBO.png) to show you what is happening. It is not possible to include/use the `Google.Apis` as you can see.

Comment: I tried to `nuget install Google.Apis.Drive.v3` too on my machine, but [this is what I got](https://i.imgur.com/GW8ycvE.png). I am confused on how to move on. Any idea that I can apply to solve the problem?

Comment: The programming language I am using is `C#`, and installation of packages I did is not via `npm install` but I may be wrong. I used for now `sudo dotnet add package PACKAGENAME`, but tdid not work.

Comment: Hi @Emanuele , I have updated my answer to include the C#/.NET installation guide and command. Let me know if this works. Check out the C# section and link to learn how to use Drive in your .NET application.

Comment: Ok thanks, it works. **NOTE**: For all `Ubuntu-18.04` users that wish to install via command line the correct way is: `sudo dotnet add package Google.Apis.Drive.v3`.